# Замена элементов массива элементами массива

Tags: массивы, c

У меня есть массив.

Я нашёл тот элемент массива который мне нужен, теперь мне нужно поставить его на первое место. Как мне это сделать?

Чтобы было яснее, брошу саму задачу:

> Дан массив действительных чисел, содержащий 25 элементов, записать в
>   этот же массив сначала все положительные числа и нули, а затем все
>   отрицательные, сохраняя порядок их следования.

Comment: Например, так:

    temp = arr[target];
    for ( ; target > 0; target--)
        arr[target] = arr[target - 1];
    arr[0] = temp;

Comment: Кстати, поиск по stackoverflow не нашёл `O(n)`-алгоритма stable partition (собственно, то, что вам здесь нужно по большому счёту). Алгоритм c `O(n log n)` найти легко — это сортировка по составному ключу `(sign v, index)`.

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к ответу [[@ProkletyiPirat](/users/8821/prokletyipirat)](/users/8821/prokletyipirat): можно применить к массиву устойчивую сортировку, с компаратором, не различающим между собой числа одного типа:

```
int comp(int a, int b) {
  if (a >= 0 && b < 0)
    return -1;
  if (a < 0 && b >= 0)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

В C++ все проще: можно воспользоваться `std::stable_sort` с компаратором:

```
[](int a, int b) {   return a >= 0 && b < 0; }
```

**UPD**: удалил бредовый параграф про `qsort`.

Comment: ОЙ ОЙ ОЙ

Ой зло, зло это!

зачем молодое поколение так сразу гробить? (в смысле скила, а не возраста)

да спору нет, решение грамотное и оправданное для человека со "скилом" даже для джуниора, НО только не для человека который не может поменять местами пару значений в массиве и в добавок не познал тёмную сторону цикла!

эт, так, на лирику потянуло...

Comment: @dzhioev: А можно ли использовать неантисимметричный компаратор? Для `cmp(a, b) = (a >= 0 && b < 0)` не выполняется свойство

    cmp(a, b) > 0 => cmp(b, a) < 0

(то есть, это не является отношением строгого порядка). Не вылетит?

Comment: Вот только традиционный `qsort`, реализующий алгоритм `quicksort` не относится к устойчивым сортировкам.

--

Реализация `qsort()` в ununtu (по крайней мере в ней) использует алгоритм сортировки слиянием (это устойчивая сортировка), но если размер сортируемого массива превышает половину (IMHO, точно сейчас не помню) физической памяти, то вместо `mergesort` применяется `quicksort` (а она неустойчивая).

*Такая, вот, засада!!!*

--

А если эту задачу решать за линейное время, то понадобится вспомогательная память (до полмассива) и 3 прохода.

Comment: @avp: ... или целый массив и 2 прохода.

Comment: Да, со стабильной сортировкой через qsort я лажанул. Самое смешное, что я подчерпнул эту глупость (про сравнение адресов), на сайте GNU. http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Array-Sort-Function.html : "If you want the effect of a stable sort, you can get this result by writing the comparison function so that, lacking other reason distinguish between two elements, it compares them by their addresses. Note that doing this may make the sorting algorithm less efficient, so do it only if necessary."

Comment: @dzhioev, а ведь такой компаратор (учитывающий адрес, т.е. по сути с соствным ключем) **в самом деле будет работать**. 

Мне это даже в голову не приходило.

Comment: @avp, только надо адреса запоминать заранее, а не как в моем примере, где я использовал текущий адрес элемента.

Answer (score 1):

ну то что вы просите очень просто, а именно

1. создать дополнительную переменную и
       записать в неё то что нашли
2. сдвинуть все значения в нужную
       сторону
3. на освободившееся место записать то значение из временной переменной

---

---

---

проще пройти по массиву и сравнивать два соседних значения, если с слева отрицательное а справа нет то поменять местами, и так до тех пор пока есть что менять

p.s. ну есть и более быстрые сортировки :)

Comment: ну а если подряд идут несколько отрицательных чисел,и тогда мне нужно не сравнивать с следующим числом,а с предыдущим)так как вы говорите,программа будет работать не полностью)

Comment: всё полностью! если **немножечко** подумать и вспомнить о существовании циклов и условий в них...

ну и собственно весь ответ я уже дал